# Can these tags be created/merged/synonym-ed?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I think the [contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts) tag should have a synonym of "people" as the new contact/people manager in android 4.0 is now called people.

I also noticed that we have a tag [xyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xyboard). This should probably be changed to motorola-xyboard, or maybe even motorola-droid-xyboard to follow the same naming as the other device tags.

Comment: The latter is done.  I think there might be a valid distinction between contacts in general and the apps.  Perhaps `contacts-app` and `people-app` should be synonyms, with `contacts` remaining for the general case.

Comment: @MatthewRead if that is the case, the tagwiki needs to be updated. it says the questions should be 'about the built-in app for managing Contacts or a manufacturer enhanced version. By default, the Contacts app synchronizes with the Contacts app associated with your Google account.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be careful about merging the 'contacts' and 'people'. Isn't the app in HTC Sense called "People"?

Also, 2.x and 3.x versions of Android are going to be around (and generating questions) for quite some time yet.

I think Matthew Read's suggestion of creating "contacts-app" and "people-app" is a good one, although I don't think I'm in favor of making one a synonym of the other. They will at least offer a way to distinguish from questions about contacts in general.

Comment: I concur with Matthew's suggestion.